# NSMenuItem image is distorted when drawn

Tags: objective-c, image, nsmenuitem, macos-big-sur

I'm building up a list of submenu items, that contain an image. I do load an image from the bundle, then want to draw it in the menu item swatch.

Here's the code:

```
  NSMenuItem *item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];

  [item setAction:@selector(action:)];
  [item setTarget:self];
  [item setEnabled:YES];

  NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(24, 16)];

  [img lockFocus];

  NSString *imgFile = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"swatch" ofType: @"png"];
  NSImage *swtch = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgFile];

  NSRect imgRect;
  imgRect.origin = NSZeroPoint;
  imgRect.size = [swtch size];
  [swtch drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 24, 16)
           fromRect:imgRect
          operation:NSCompositingOperationSourceOver
           fraction:1.0f];

  [img unlockFocus];

  [item setImage:[img copy]];
```

If I select the menu item from the submenu, the NSPopupButton displays the correct image.

[image: popup button]

If I get a bitmap representation from "img", it is correct, a downsized copy of "swtch".

But the menu item looks wrong:

[image: menu item image]

It only started this on Big Sur, prevoiusly all looked good.
Do I need to setup menu item or its cell different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in the image itself. It probably has an alpha channel, but the antialiasing around the text edges was composited on a white background (hard to explain, but it can and does happen depending on how the image was made.)

Does this image always draw on a white background? If so, try re-saving the .png file without transparency. You can do this in Preview.app. File->Export, uncheck Alpha.

If you need black antialiased text that composites properly atop any colored background, you'd need to redo the image so there's no white in it. This can be done in Photoshop.

(You might also be able to fix it by changing the blend mode to something like `NSCompositingOperationDarken` or `NSCompositingOperationPlusDarker`, but it would be cleaner to repair the image file.)

Comment: The image is a PNG but no alpha channel. The background is solid white.
Tried to "remove the alpha channel" as you described but the option "Alpha" was not present. I confirmed by substituting the image with one that actually HAS the alpha channel and it was there.

Images used did not change in the past year, but the difference is between previous Catalina and current Big Sur macOS version.

Comment: If I add an image with transparent background, everything goes fine (except for the background missing, obviously), no distortion. Tried different background colors, no difference. Images are not changed when bundled while compiling the app.

Comment: Finally, I guess I would need to try other image editing programs (beside Preview and AffinityDesigner/Photo) but filling the target image with white background and using `NSCompositingOperationDarken` solved the problem.

Comment: I was struggling with this too. From my testing it seems to be isolated to MacOS 11.x but didn't test on earlier OS's. I noticed it whenever the image was on a white background, like a product shot, the edges would show artifacting where the darker colors met white. Did it on Intel and Apple Silicon machines and the OS was the only variance I could pin down. NSCompositingOperationDarken fixed it for me.